# Image inserted in css-grid row causes parent to overflow

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the entire page layout created using CSS grid. it is divided into five parts (nav, footer and so on). One of those parts (`#siteAds` in the code below) is also a grid, consisting of one column and five rows. I want to insert an image into one of those rows, I'm using the following to make it fit:

```
   img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

EDIT: My problem here is that after the image is added the size of the element containing it expands. Since it is inserted into a grid row that has its size already specified, I was expecting the image to be scaled down exactly to the size of the row. In other words I thought that the size of the parent element would remain the same no matter whether the image is there or not, but it actually expands. Also, after the image is added, this expansion causes the page to overflow and the scrollbar appears, despite that there's no content being out bounds (at least on my screen). See the pictures below for comparison between what happens when the image is there vs when its display is set to none.

Image added, the page overflows, despite that there is still quite a bit of empty space in the column in question:
[image: Image added, the page overflows, despite that there is still quite a bit of empty space in the column in question]

Image display set to none, no overflow:
[image: image display set to none, no overflow]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav article ads" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

header,
footer,
article,
nav,
#siteAds {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: grey;
}

#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
}

#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
}

#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
}

#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

#siteAds {
  grid-area: ads;
}

#siteAds {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 7% 5% 5% 20% 1fr;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

#adsHeader {
  font-size: 35px;
}

#adsSubHeading {
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

.adsImage {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<title>CSS Grid Test</title>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header id="pageHeader">Header</header>
    <article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
    <nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>

    <div id="siteAds">

      <div id="adsHeader">Text here</div>
      <div id="adsSubHeading">Text here</div>


      <div class="adsHeading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="adsContentImage">
        <img class="adsImage" src="https://www.neweurope.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/h_55941379-1068x712.jpg" alt="placeholder">
      </div>
      <div class="adsContentText">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae nisi eu dolor sollicitudin tristique. Aenean sollicitudin, augue vel pulvinar rutrum, ex enim semper nisi, eleifend imperdiet dolor massa vel nunc. Integer eleifend non nisi
          at pharetra. Vivamus rhoncus, erat non consectetur facilisis, ante arcu condimentum ante, vitae condimentum dui ante ac tellus. Maecenas interdum bibendum libero ut dictum. Morbi tortor mauris, ullamcorper eu velit ac, malesuada varius ipsum.
          </p>
        <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam quis pretium elit, non ultricies magna. Nunc vel nibh mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse
          posuere a ante a scelerisque. Suspendisse euismod et justo ac tincidunt. Mauris tortor nisi, vestibulum vel porta eu, tempor vel quam.</p>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor:</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Nam quis pretium elit, non ultricies magna</li>
          <li>Suspendisse euismod et justo ac tincidunt</li>
          <li>Nam quis pretium elit, non ultricies magna</li>
          <li>Suspendisse euismod et justo ac tincidunt</li>

        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I’m not clear that adding the img has any effect. If I make the img display none I still see the text overflowing.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear. I've edited my question, hopefully it makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the system is somehow using the img aspect ratio when fitting, but I cannot fully explain the scroll addition.

A workaround is to display the image as a background with size cover. Its natural dimensions/aspect ratio cannot then influence the element’s size.

Here’s a simple snippet which uses a div plus background rather than an image.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav article ads" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

header,
footer,
article,
nav,
#siteAds {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: grey;
}

#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
}

#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
}

#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
}

#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

#siteAds {
  grid-area: ads;
}

#siteAds {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 7% 5% 5% 20% 1fr;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

#adsHeader {
  font-size: 35px;
}

#adsSubHeading {
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

.adsImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<title>CSS Grid Test</title>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header id="pageHeader">Header</header>
    <article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
    <nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>

    <div id="siteAds">

      <div id="adsHeader">Text here</div>
      <div id="adsSubHeading">Text here</div>


      <div class="adsHeading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="adsContentImage">
        <div class="adsImage" style="background-image: url(https://www.neweurope.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/h_55941379-1068x712.jpg); background-size: cover;"alt="placeholder"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="adsContentText">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae nisi eu dolor sollicitudin tristique. Aenean sollicitudin, augue vel pulvinar rutrum, ex enim semper nisi, eleifend imperdiet dolor massa vel nunc. Integer eleifend non nisi
          at pharetra. Vivamus rhoncus, erat non consectetur facilisis, ante arcu condimentum ante, vitae condimentum dui ante ac tellus. Maecenas interdum bibendum libero ut dictum. Morbi tortor mauris, ullamcorper eu velit ac, malesuada varius ipsum.
          </p>
        <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam quis pretium elit, non ultricies magna. Nunc vel nibh mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse
          posuere a ante a scelerisque. Suspendisse euismod et justo ac tincidunt. Mauris tortor nisi, vestibulum vel porta eu, tempor vel quam.</p>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor:</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Nam quis pretium elit, non ultricies magna</li>
          <li>Suspendisse euismod et justo ac tincidunt</li>
          <li>Nam quis pretium elit, non ultricies magna</li>
          <li>Suspendisse euismod et justo ac tincidunt</li>

        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```